# File upload and download in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any problem with the code below?  Because I can click the button without error, but the file will not save into the `"public_html/resume/"`

```
$uploadOk = true;

if(isset($_FILES)) {

    $folder_dir = "public_html/resume/";

    $base = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']); 

    $resumeFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

    $file = uniqid() . "." . $resumeFileType;   

    $filename = $folder_dir .$file;  

    if(file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) { 

        if($resumeFileType == "pdf")  {

            if($_FILES['resume']['size'] < 500000) { // File size is less than 5MB

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $filename);

            } else {
                $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
                header("Location: edit-profile.php");
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only PDF Allowed";
            header("Location: edit-profile.php");
            exit();
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: needless to say you're missing `}` in the code but also check if  you have access to `public_html/resume`. it seems more like a permission issue

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Is `$file` what you expect?  Is `$filename` what you expect?  Are you getting inside the `if(file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) {` check?

Comment: not error message was found when I click upload when the path folder was empty

Comment: Add error handling: https://www.tinywebhut.com/errors-and-custom-error-handling-in-php-56

Comment: it will be better if you share your view file. check whether you add enctype=multipart/form-data  in you form

Comment: Unfortunately petty much every single line of your PHP code can and should be improved.

Comment: use absolute path `$folder_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resume/";`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately petty much every single line of your PHP code should be improved.

The reason for your error was that `/public_hml/` was not an *absolute* file path so PHP was interpreting it as *relative*. and looking for `<current directory>/public_html/resume/` which is almost certainly invalid.

I have fixed pretty much everything for you, below.

```
$uploadOk = false; // Always assume false until proven ok.  

if(!empty($_FILES['resume'])) {
   // Check errors    
   if($_FILES['resume']['error'] === 0){

        $folder_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resume/"; // use absolute path.

    // $base = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']); //worthless.
    // $resumeFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

        $finfo = new finfo();
        $fileMimeType = $finfo->file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'], FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        if(strtolower($fileMimeType) !== 'applicaton/pdf'){
               $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format. Only PDF Allowed";
                header("Location: edit-profile.php");
                exit();
        }
        $file = uniqid("",true) . ".PDF";    // make sure unique is unique. 

        $filename = $folder_dir .$file;  

    //if(file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) {  

    //   if($resumeFileType == "pdf")  {//worthless.

       if($_FILES['resume']['size'] > 500000) { // File size is less than 5MB
            $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
            header("Location: edit-profile.php");
            exit();
       } 

       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $filename);
   }
   else {
     //There were file upload errors. Handle here.
    }
}
```

## Source

- [Is there a way to check the filetype of a file uploaded using PHP?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57856/is-there-a-way-to-check-the-filetype-of-a-file-uploaded-using-php)
- [PHP Manaul POST method uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)