# my previously store data are automatically deleted while updating a data

Tags: php

I am currently working on a job portal project, where I can store user information,
in my project after registration, user can go there dashboard, and update there remaining form like, education detail and company detail. but after that when user like to update one of the any field in form, it can update that field but it can delete my remaining field, in education detail field or company detail field. What kind of this problem is occurred ?

*updateprofile.php*

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id_user']))
{
  header("Location: ../index.php");
  exit();
}
require_once("../db.php");

if(isset($_POST))
{
    //Escape Special Characters
    $firstname = $conn->real_escape_string( $_POST['fname']);
    $lastname = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
    $gender = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
    $contactno = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['contactno']);
    $address = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $city = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
    $state = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['state']);
    $aboutme = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['aboutme']);
    $qualification = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['qualification']);
    $stream = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['stream']);
    $coursetype = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['coursetype']);
    $university = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['university']);
    $passingyear = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['passingyear']);
    $skill = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['skill']);
    $industry = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['industry']);
    $functional_area = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['functional_area']);
    $role = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['role']);
    $is_current_job = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['is_current_job']);
    $startdate = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['startdate']);
    $enddate = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['enddate']);
    $current_compname = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['current_compname']);
    $current_salary = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['current_salary']);
    $designation = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['designation']);
    $notice_period = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['notice_period']);
    $job_desc = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['job_desc']);
    $experience = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['experience']);
    $current_location = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['current_location']);
    $prefer_location = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['prefer_location']);
    $uploadOk = true;


if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) 
    {
        $folder_dir = "../uploads/resume/";
        $base = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']); 
        $resumeFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
        $file = uniqid() . "." . $resumeFileType;   
        $filename = $folder_dir .$file;     
        if(file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name']))      
        { 

            if($resumeFileType == "pdf")                
            {
                if($_FILES['resume']['size'] < 500000) 
                { 
                    // File size is less than 5MB
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $filename);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size of file. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
                    header("Location: edit_profile.php");
                    exit();
                }
            } 
            else
            {
              $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format of file only pdf Allowed.";
              header("Location: edit_profile.php");
              exit();
            }


        }               

    } 
    else 
    {
        $uploadOk = false;
    }

    //Update User Details Query
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname',gender='$gender',contactno='$contactno', address='$address', city='$city', state='$state',aboutme='$aboutme',qualification='$qualification', stream='$stream',coursetype='$coursetype',university='$university',passingyear='$passingyear',skill='$skill',
    industry='$industry',functional_area='$function_area',role='$role',is_current_job='$is_current_job',startdate='$startdate',enddate='$enddate',current_compname='$current_compname',current_salary='$current_salary',designation='$designation',notice_period='$notice_period',job_desc='$job_desc',experience='$experience',current_location='$current_location',prefer_location='$prefer_location'";


    if($uploadOk == true)
    {
        $sql .= ",resume='$file'";
    }
    $sql .= " WHERE id_user='$_SESSION[id_user]'";


    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        //If data Updated successfully then redirect to dashboard
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Error ". $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    //Close database connection.
    $conn->close();
}
else 
{
    //redirect them back to dashboard page if they didn't click update button
    header("Location: edit_profile.php");
    exit();
}
```

*image of user table*

[image]

Comment: What is the runtime value of '$sql' when you execute that SQL code?  Are there blank values?  Do you expect those values not to be blank?  Why?

Comment: Are you constantly switching accounts to finish your project by having others write for you? Isn't [this your account and question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859622/file-upload-and-download-in-php)?

Comment: @Cemal There are some differences.  Probably working on the same assignment though.

Comment: Also in order to not update where not needed, you need to build your sql dynamically where the fields from `$_POST` are empty.

Comment: @PatrickQ if I search a bit more, I'm pretty sure I can find those different parts in an answer section of another question

Comment: @cemal what do you mean, by "switching your account to finish your project and other write for you" ?.it is my own account and my question. I can't understand what you say ?

Comment: your code awfully looks like (even the comments are same), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859622/file-upload-and-download-in-php)

Comment: @david, I want user can change those particular value not all field can be change. for eg: when user can change experience. all field that table cannot be changed except experience.

Comment: @cemal i am just questioning, what do mean by asking of that question i cant understand it. are you questioning me i am not a genuine account holder ?

Comment: I am asking not questioning. Did you copy the code from a tutorial or sthg or are you using 2 accounts to have someone write the code for you?

Comment: @cemal i am learning code from tutorials for my project and my stackoverflow account is open in my office pc and my own laptop, iam not logiin out of my office pc.

Comment: @cemal i am new in coding, can you help,in solving my error

Comment: what are you using for db operations? mysql, mysqli, pdo..?

Comment: i am usin mysqli,oops

Comment: @luckynath: Well, in your code you are explicitly updating *every* field.  If you don't have the values to set in those fields, don't set them.  There are a variety of ways you can approach this, but everything depends on your understanding of the basic logic here.  You are explicitly updating every field.  MOST of your code is for exactly that purpose.  If that's not what you want to do, then think about what you *do* want to do and how you would logically make that happen.   Personally for a simple form like this I'd include every field on the page and always update them all.

Comment: @cemal i have a question? i have one form for all those field, so when i am updating one field, it  can null my all other field ?,or i can use different form, for education detail and company detail? or use different table?

Comment: why my question is downvoted

Comment: @luckynath: *"when i am updating one field, it can null my all other field"* - Only if you update those fields to a null value.  Are you doing that?  If all of your fields are on your form, why are they being set to empty values?  Perhaps the user is emptying them in the form?  Debug what's happening in your code.  As originally asked, where do you *expect* your other values to come from?  *Why?*  And how have you *confirmed* that they are?

Answer (score 0):

Using prepared statements and dynamic field mapping to update only those fields which has value in it, here is what your code should look like

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (empty($_SESSION['id_user'])) {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
        exit();
    }
    require_once("../db.php");

    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $uploadOk = true;


        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) {
            $folder_dir = "../uploads/resume/";
            $base = basename($_FILES['resume']['name']);
            $resumeFileType = pathinfo($base, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $file = uniqid() . "." . $resumeFileType;
            $filename = $folder_dir . $file;
            if (file_exists($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'])) {

                if ($resumeFileType == "pdf") {
                    if ($_FILES['resume']['size'] < 500000) {
                        // File size is less than 5MB
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $filename);
                    } else {
                        $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Size of file. Max Size Allowed : 5MB";
                        header("Location: edit_profile.php");
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['uploadError'] = "Wrong Format of file only pdf Allowed.";
                    header("Location: edit_profile.php");
                    exit();
                }


            }

        } else {
            $uploadOk = false;
        }

        //Update User Details Query
        $postf2sqlf = array(
            'firstname'        => 'firstname',
            'lastname'         => 'lastname',
            'gender'           => 'gender',
            'contactno'        => 'contactno',
            'address'          => 'address',
            'city'             => 'city',
            'state'            => 'state',
            'aboutme'          => 'aboutme',
            'qualification'    => 'qualification',
            'stream'           => 'stream',
            'coursetype'       => 'coursetype',
            'university'       => 'university',
            'passingyear'      => 'passingyear',
            'skill'            => 'skill',
            'industry'         => 'industry',
            'functional_area'  => 'function_area',
            'role'             => 'role',
            'is_current_job'   => 'is_current_job',
            'startdate'        => 'startdate',
            'enddate'          => 'enddate',
            'current_compname' => 'current_compname',
            'current_salary'   => 'current_salary',
            'designation'      => 'designation',
            'notice_period'    => 'notice_period',
            'job_desc'         => 'job_desc',
            'experience'       => 'experience',
            'current_location' => 'current_location',
            'prefer_location'  => 'prefer_location'
        );

        $sql = 'UPDATE `user` SET ';
        $skipComma = true;
        $params = array('');
        foreach ($postf2sqlf as $p => $s) {
            if (isset($_POST[$p]) && !empty($_POST[$p])) {
                $sql .= ($skipComma ? '' : ',') . '`' . $s . '` = ?';
                $params[] = &$_POST[$p];
                $params[0] .= 's';
                $skipComma = false;
            }
        }

        if ($uploadOk == true) {
            $sql .= ",resume=?";
            $params = &$file;
            $params[0] .= 's';
        }
        $sql .= " WHERE id_user=?";
        $params[0] .= 's';
        $params[] = &$_SESSION['id_user'];

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
        $res = $stmt->execute();


        if ($stmt->errno == 0) {
            //If data Updated successfully then redirect to dashboard
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "Error " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        //Close database connection.
        $conn->close();
    } else {
        //redirect them back to dashboard page if they didn't click update button
        header("Location: edit_profile.php");
        exit();
    }
```

**Explanation**

- Created `$postf2sqlf` array, holding the Form fields as index, and sql field names as value.
- Iterating over `$postf2sqlf` and checking if the index is set and not empty in `$_POST`, started collecting the parameters passing references in `$params` to use in a prepared statement to avoid SQL Injection. `$params[0]` holds the type (s => string) of named parameters, as `mysqli_statement::bind_param` requires this, and as parameters added, another s is concatenated. (For a strict sql, instead of s, other types could be used upon checking their types but for simplicity's sake I used s)
- The reason to collect variables by passing references is because `mysqli_statement::bind_param requires the variables pass by references.
- `call_user_func_array` was used to call `mysqli_statement::bind_param` with the `$params` with each index being a different argument.
- Finally, `$stmt->errno` was checked against 0 (0 being no errors), to check that it was actually completed correctly.